# Teste com protractor, como pegar um md-button?

Tags: angularjs, testes

Estou usando o Protractor para testar um sistema feito em Angularjs e Material, estou tendo problemas com o locator quando quero pegar um md-button especifico em um formulário e executar o click().
O hmtl do botão é esse:

```
<md-card-actions layout="column" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap layout-sm="column">
            <md-button 
                ng-disabled="!loginForm.$valid || Login.inProgress"
                class="md-raised lightBlue buttonLogin" 
                type="submit"
                aria-label="{{'login.enter' | translate}}"
                ng-click="Login.login(authForm)">
                    <span translate="login.enter"></span>
                    <md-progress-linear 
                        md-mode="indeterminate"
                        ng-show="Login.inProgress">
                    </md-progress-linear>
            </md-button>

            <md-button ng-click="Login.fbLogin()" aria-label="{{'login.loginFacebookLink' | translate}}" class="md-raised md-primary lightBlue">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="icons/facebook_.svg"></md-icon>
                <span translate="login.loginFacebookLink"> </span>
            </md-button>

            <md-button class="md-raised md-warn md-hue-2" aria-label="{{'login.forgotPasswordLink' | translate}}" ng-click="Login.buttonCallForgotPassword();">
                <span translate="login.forgotPasswordLink"> </span>
            </md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
```

Trecho do código de teste:

```
var button = element.all(by.css('button.lightBlue')).first();

button.click();
```

Coloquei o first() só para pegar o primeiro botão, mas não sei se o primeiro botão que ele lista é o do login.

Preciso pegar o primeiro botão, as vezes da um alerta dizendo que tem mais de um botão e que executou no primeiro, porem, como vou ter que testar os três botões preciso saber qual estou usando.
Como faço para pegar um botão em especifico quando uso md-button ?

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar desta maneira:

`element(by.css('md-button[ng-click="Login.login(authForm)"]')).click()`